# How to bind gridview using Jquery after upload of the data using the Fileupload control

Tags: asp.net

Recently I was working on a requirement as mentioned below:

1. There is a webform containing FileUpload control and below it there is a gridiview control.
2. When user clicks the browse button of the Fileupload control and picks an image to upload the image should now be available in the gridview using Jquery.
3. The binding of the gridview with the image source from Fileupload control should be done using Jquery.

Can anyone help me out with any code sample.

Thanks In Advance,

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correctly understand you, the one possible way to implement something similar to this requirement is to place gridview into UpdatePanel and use async file upload control like the AsyncFileUpload from the AjaxControlToolkit library or some else. With such control you can handle it's event fired in the client-side after the file successfully uploaded and call `__doPostBack` function in that event handler to re-bind gridview on server.